# this code is giving me a else: ^ IndentationError: unexpected unindent error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
        elif pluput == "stop":
            try:
                if atks == 0:
                    print("no attacks running")
                    main()
                else:
                    attack = False
                    print("                  [\033[34mplu\033[00m] stoped all running attacks")
                    while not attack:
                        if atks == 0:
                            attack = True
        else:
            main()
try:
    clear = "clear"
    os.system(clear)
    print(banner)
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("\n                  [\033[34mplu\033[00m] CTRL has been pressed")
    main()
```

Comment: The first `try` needs an `except` block

Comment: mentioning on which line you get the error usually helps in answering the question, or make a comment in the code

Answer (score 0):

every `try` in python need to have a exception

```
    elif pluput == "stop":
        try:
            if atks == 0:
                print("no attacks running")
                main()
            else:
                attack = False
                print("                  [\033[34mplu\033[00m] stoped all running attacks")
                while not attack:
                    if atks == 0:
                        attack = True
         except:
             print("some error")
    else:
        main()
try:
    clear = "clear"
    os.system(clear)
    print(banner)
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("\n                  [\033[34mplu\033[00m] CTRL has been pressed")
    main()
```